# Connection Refused message when performed operations using HTTPGet and HTTPPost

Tags: access-token, bearer-token

I am currently working on automating API using HttpGet and HttpPost requests in java.
The Authorization requires dynamic Access tokens to be generated.

I tried to get the access token using the below code in java
HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://..../oauth/token?username=user&password=pass&grant_type=password");
post.setHeader("Authorization", "Basic cmVsdGlvX3VpO");
HttpResponse response1 = client.execute(post);

But the above code gives Connection refused message. This is suspected to be because of proxy issue... I tried many ways to solve this issue but nothing helped. Is there any way to fix this issue?

Can anyone let me know if there is a way to generate the bearer tokens dynamically using java code?

Comment: The specification requires that request parameters be embedded in the request body, but it seems that your code embeds request parameters as query parameters.

Comment: @Takahiko Thanks for your answer .

Answer (score 0):

@Tavkahiko Thanks for providing your input for my question.

My issue is resolved.
It was mainly due to Proxy issue I was getting connection refused issue.
After adding the proxy as shown below my issue was resolved for API POST Operation

```
HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost("www.test.com", 8080);
Credentials credentials = new UsernamePasswordCredentials("test", "test@321"); 
AuthScope authScope = new AuthScope(AuthScope.ANY_HOST, AuthScope.ANY_PORT);
CredentialsProvider credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
credsProvider.setCredentials(authScope, credentials);
HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().setProxy(proxy).setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credsProvider).build();
```

After performing post operation on the below url, I got the accesstoken in the response body. Using which I was able to perform GET Operation using the bearer token.
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://..../oauth/token?username=user&password=pass&grant_type=password");

Even after setting the proxy I was getting issue for API Get operation 
    HttpGet get = new HttpGet(apiURL);

Issue was with the apiURL... If you declare apiURL as string for Get operation you might get 407 Error.
Make sure you declare apiURL as URI apiURL= new uri("http://test.auth.com/...");